# How do I show all recently added documents within all folders?

Tags: web-part

Hi I tried to create a view in the recently added documents webpart to filtering only on documents created, because it was showing folders too. When I created the view nothing was populating, which made me thing the recently added docs webpart does not dig deeper than level one.  Is this true?  If so, how can I show recently documents added withing all folders?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is a setting inside list views called "Folders" which you can choose whether or not to show folders or a flat list and whether to show top level or all levels